# Why does type constructor pattern matching require the argument to be the constructor's type

Tags: haskell

For example, i want to write the following function:

```
isTree Leaf = "True"
isTree Node {} = "True"
isTree  _       = "False"
```

that takes any type and returns `True` only if an argument of type `Tree a` was passed. But this is impossible. Why?

Comment: What do you mean with "that's impossible". I'm not entirely following?

Comment: @WillemVOsupportsmodstrike I think OP wants to be able to pass values of any type to the function, and to get "False" rather than a compiler error if it's not a `Tree a`.

Comment: I mean, that type of `isTree :: Tree a -> [Char]`. And I'm asking why it's not possible to put an arbitrary type so that the `isTree 1` code works. What problems can this lead to?

Comment: That particular thing doesn't lead to problems by itself. Problems arise from the very possibility of making such function. Problems with dynamic typing are too broad and graphic to explain in a comment. But in return for making it impossible, Haskell also makes it unnecessary. Think about this carefully: how would you actually use such function?

Comment: @otstalyi: one of the main features of Haskell is *full type erasure*, that means that after the compiler phase, at runtime, the objects don't need to be labeled with a type, as is done in a lot of other languages.

Comment: Types don't exist at runtime, so you need something like `Data.Typeable` to provide data-level representations of types.

Comment: But as said, it is not necessary. Why? For the very same reason: we know what the type will be at compile time, so if the expression you pass to the function is not a tree, then it makes no sense at all to use this.

Comment: Rather than ask "what problems can this lead to?" (the obvious answer being, type-unsafe code), you should ask "what problem would allowing this *solve*?". (*Your* function is type-safe, because you don't do anything with a value of unknown type, but accepting values of any type would not prevent code like `oops :: Any -> Str; oops Leaf = "True"; oops x = show (x + 1)`. You are basically asking the type checker to ignore the type mismatches it exists to find.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pattern match different types. Types *don't exist* at runtime, they're only there for the compiler to check your code, link the correct type class, etc..

It is possible to write a function that "takes any type"

```
isTree :: a -> Bool
```

but such a function can't actually do anything at all with its argument. I mean, technically speaking you might be able to read the address and do arithmetic with it, but Haskell doesn't allow that for good reasons.

At any rate you wouldn't be able to do pattern matching, because two different types may use the same binary representation to express completely different things. It's like, in assembly there's no way to distinguish the values `121` and `'y'`, they're just two different interpretations of the bit pattern `01111001`.

Of course, some programming languages do explicitly store the type information along with each value, but this is generally redundant: if the code has been type checked, there isn't any need for looking "what type does this value have", because the compiler has already made sure beforehand that any value that could possibly be given there does have the single appropriate type.

Of course, there *are* reasons why you might want to pass values of different types to a function. The simplest option is to use a variant type:

```
data TreeOrElse = YeahATree Tree
                | NopeNotATree (Int, [Double])

isTree :: TreeOrElse -> Bool
isTree (YeahATree _) = True
isTree (NopeNotATree _) = False
```

If you really want to permit passing any type and checking if it is particularly `Tree` (which is probably a bad idea), you also need to explicitly pass the information on. This is what [`Dynamic`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Data-Dynamic.html) allows:

```
import Data.Dynamic

isTree :: Dynamic -> Bool
```

To implement this, you need your type to be an instance of the `Typeable` class

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

data Tree = ...
 deriving (Typeable, ...)

isTree t = case fromDynamic t :: Maybe Tree of
  Nothing -> False
  Just _ -> True
```